# ServiceProvider not found laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm creating a composer installable project inside vendor.
This is my service provider file,

```
<?php
namespace vimuths123\gitpack;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class GitpackServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register() {
        $this->app->bind('gitpack', function ($app) {
            return new Gitpack;
        });
    }

    public function boot() {
        // loading the routes file
        require __DIR__ . '/Http/routes.php';

        // define the path for the view files
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../views', 'gitpack');
    }
}
```

This is the structure,

```
vendor
      |
     vimuths123
        |-gitpack
           |-src
           |  |-GitpackServiceProvider.php
           |
           |-composer.json
```

I already added my service provider in app/config.php

```
 vimuths123\gitpack\GitpackServiceProvider::class,
```

and my root composer.json I have following code.

```
"psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "vimuths123\\gitpack\\" : "vendor/vimuths123/gitpack/src"
        }
```

This is my package composer file,

```
{
    "name": "vimuths123/gitpack",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "vimuths123\\gitpack\\" : "src" 
         }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.2"
    }
}
```

but all I'm getting is this error,

> Class 'vimuths123\gitpack\GitpackServiceProvider' not found

It would be great help someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

You should not put any files into `vendor/` by hand. If you are developing a library it must be composer installable library (which once installed end up in `vendor/`.

Your `composer.json` seems wrong, especially `vendor/vimuths123/gitpack/src` name space in `psr4`. This's smells from a mile as I'd bet you not using `vendor/vimuths123/gitpack/src` namespace.

Finally, after adding new class you should update class loader to let it know about that:

```
composer dumpautoload
```

which solves most of problems with "cannot find my class" issues.

**EDIT**

It seems your problems are in your library package, not the project using it. From comments it looks that you need to edit your **package's** `composer.json`. Assuming package is using `vimuths123\gitpack` namespace (note, namespace does NOT have to be the same as package name - these are two different things) and its sources sit in `src` subfolder (so it would be `<project>/vendor/vimuths123/gitpack/src`) then I'd rework `autoload` section to look like this:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4" : {
       "vimuths123\\gitpack\\" : "src" 
    }
}
```

and then `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: I downloaded this github repo via composer so it downloaded to vendor. And I ran composer dump-autoload command and tried removing vendor/vimuths123/gitpack/src line too really sorry but it was still not working

Comment: If this is a package released via packagist, then `composer install` is sufficient. You should not be needing to do anything as all shall be set up by package's `composer.json`, which includes paths for loader. I'd remove it completely and consider using project issues page on github

Comment: It's a simple package created by me and it's not registered in packagist. I just added "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/vimuths123/gitpack"
        }
    ] in composer.json and downloaded it

Comment: Then your package should set psr4 part - it will be used by composer. so you need to fix your package not the app

Comment: package has this composer.json file but I'm not sure how to change it,
{
    "name": "vimuths123/gitpack",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
            "vimuths123\\gitpack" : "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.2"
    }
}

Comment: I added my package composer.json file these line and ran a composer autoload really sorry but it's still not working

Answer (score -1):

Run the following `artisan` command:

```
php artisan optimize
```

Then see if the class can be found by Laravel.